# window.load is executing before document.ready

Tags: jquery

i am beginner to jquery. I am going through followng video tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7JaPcGQYtk&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVDV697uvHpavA3K_eWGQap&spfreload=5

He mentioned, window.load executes after the DOM, images, css etc., are loaded and document.read() executes once the DOM is ready. So document.ready event always executes before window.load event. But when I tried following snippet, window.load is executing before document.ready. Can any one tell me, am I doing any mistake (or) is this is the expected behavior.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>window load vs document ready</title>
        <script src = "jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

            jq(document).ready(function(){
                alert("Document is loaded");
            });

            jq(window).on("load", function(){
                alert("Window is ready");
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a difference between the DOM being ready or the window being loaded. The DOM is only ready when all images on it are loaded for instance. The window is then loaded before the DOM is ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems some problem with JQuery 3.1.0
Tried it with 2.4 and 1.1
Its working as expected

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
                alert('Window onload');
        };
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('document');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="a.jpg">
</body></html>
```

Hmm... .Using Jquery 3.3.1,  I tried the above by adding an img tag and document.ready executes first. I may be wrong, but this makes me believe that when there are other tags, perhaps window.onload waits and $().ready fires first.Without the img tag, window.onload runs first...